# vaginal self-examination

Tags: fiqh

Can i look and touch my genitals not for masturbation but for a vaginal self-examination and a better understanding of my organ?
I understand that masturbation is wrong and is condemned by most scholars, but i remember reading somewhere that you can insert your finger in your genitals but not for the purpose of an orgasm. i need to know since i have certain concerns about the health of my organ

Comment: If you're concerned about your health, I'd suggest visiting a doctor.

Comment: well, I think you can, and you SHOULD NOT prefer to visit the doctor(let doctor to examine). You can examine it for yourself until you don't fall prey to your most afraid thing, the so called "Masturbation"....

Comment: I'm saying that she would speak to a female doctor about her concerns. After that, the doctor will make suggestions and OP can accept or reject them. But it would probably be best to talk to the doctor and see what they have to say at the least.

Answer (score -2):

its all depends on your motive,

god is all knowing, there are so many way better to do experiment, using yourself as a guinea pig is not a wise decision . consider if you are doing amputation experiment, and you have to cut someone fingers, will you cut your own fingers for better understanding of yourself?